# Oracle Concurrent Requests/Retrieve on a very large Table

Tags: oracle

I1. I will have a very large table with around 1 billion records(pre-populated) and will have 15-20 columns with record_id as the key.

I2. We get multiple files daily and each file will have thousands of records and each record should be assigned a record id while processing these records. We also get some requests from the web application where a pool of record ids will be reserved in the back end.

I3. Plan is to write a stored procedure to retrieve the available record id/ids and assign to each record (or) to web UI request.

Q1. How can I achieve concurrent processing here? As the same record id or pool of record ids can't be assigned to multiple records (or) to WEB UI request, how can I achieve concurrent processing here?

Q2. If a file with 1000 records comes, I will be calling stored procedure to process this file. At that time if I get any other file with few more thousand records, How will/should Oracle handles this scenario. Is there any Queue concept in oracle (or) oracle by default locks each request and handles one request at a time in sequence?

Please suggest some better designs to implement this.

Comment: Go through [How to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and use formatting to make it readable.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1. How can I achieve concurrent processing here?

You can still use a sequence even if you want to have two pools of numbers:

```
create sequence web_ui_ids
    start with 1 increment by 2
/
create sequence back_end_ids
    start with 2 increment by 2
/
```

Records processed by the Web UI will have an odd ID and records processed in the back end will have an even one.

Obviously in your scenario the `start with` clause will need to take account of the back-population of records, so actually you will need something like

```
create sequence web_ui_ids
    start with 10000000001 increment by 2
/
create sequence back_end_ids
    start with 10000000002 increment by 2
/
```

If you need three pools then simply adjust the starting numbers and increments accordingly.

> Q2. ... Is there any Queue concept in oracle

Oracle has Advanced Queuing built-in. This is a messaging system, which is compatible with MQ, JMS, etc. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADQUE/aq_intro.htm#ADQUE0100).

However, it doesn't seem like you need much of a queue. You need a constantly running PL/SQL program which polls the files directory for new files. Best of doing this would be an external table with a preprocessor script to execute an `ls` (or `dir` if you run your database on Windows). [Find out more](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=513).

You only need locking if you intend to have multiple background processors. If that is your scenario you should have a table of files to be processed, and call off work using the SELECT ... FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED syntax. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/effective_apps.htm#TDDDG99922).